# Create a shortcut for APK in the Homescreen

Tags: android, apk, launcher, homescreen, apktool

I have a compiled APK and My workaround to make a shortcut at the home screen is :

```
 1- Decode the apk with apktool.jar
 2- Modify AndroidManifest (add the <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" /> )
 3- Recompile the apk and put it in the system.img
 4- with yaffey tool i replaced the file and calculate the CRC.
```

After flashing the smartphone the shortcut is not created on the Homescreen? is there any way to place the shortcut for preinstalled APK ? without code modding of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to :

> Decompile the `Launcher.apk` also.
>   Reorganize the icons positions in the XML file.
>   Recompile & sign the APK.

It works fine.