# Create Shortcut file of APK which is not installed

Tags: android, shortcut, android-download-manager

I know following things.

1. Download APK from server
2. Create App Shortcut. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337431/android-create-shortcuts-on-the-home-screen?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**My Problem:**

After Download APK in SD card, I want to create its shortcut on home screen.

So when User clicks on that shortcut, APK file will be install.

Comment: I hope this may help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349751/create-a-shortcut-for-apk-in-the-homescreen

Comment: Thanks but This link is not useful for me.